# Django is adding quotes to cookies with colons

Tags: python, django, string, cookies

I run:

```
response.set_cookie(key, value=value, expires=expires, path=path, domain=domain)
```

When the value is: `aa:aa` 
The cookie value is: `"aa:aa"`

When the value is: `aa` 
The cookie value is: `aa`

I need to prevent django from adding quotes when there are colons in the value

Comment: Perhaps try encoding with [`urllib.quote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) when you set it, and decoding with [`urllib.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) when you read it?

Comment: This behavior is probably a security measure and you should not go around it. Better remove the quotes if any when you read the cookie.

Answer (score 4):

When setting the value into cookie, just encode it using `urllib.parse.quote_plus()` or `urllib.parse.quote()`. e.g.

```
value = urllib.parse.quote_plus(value)
response.set_cookie(key, value=value, expires=expires, path=path, domain=domain)
```

And while getting value from cookie, decode it back using `urllib.parse.unquote_plus()` or `urllib.parse.unquote()` respectively. e.g.

```
if key in request.COOKIES:
    value = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(request.COOKIES[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you need that your cookies been read from other sites, you can override the response after the set_cookie

```
response.set_cookie(key, value)
response.cookies[key].coded_value = value
```